# NestedScrollView no longer working as soon as I add SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, swiperefreshlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I noticed a strange behaviour in my application.
My scrollview contains two elements.

1. a SearchView
2. a RecyclerView

Those are wrapped by an LinearLayout.
Now I want to add a SwipeRefreshLayout to refresh the data containing in the RecyclerView.
As soon as I do that the ScrollView ignores the SearchView and only scrolls through the RecyclerView.

Here is the XML:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                android:queryHint="Search Here" />

            <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/refresh"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/listRV"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

It should scroll the SearchView and the RecyclerView at the same time.
Why does it stop working as soon as I add a SwipeRefreshLayout and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by wrapping the NestedScrollView inside of the SwipeRefreshLayout.

```
  <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                    android:queryHint="Search Here" />


                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/listRV"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="gone" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```